# Glassfish v3: Web application not finding JAR in the same EAR

Tags: deployment, glassfish-3

I created a EAR application in Eclipse to run in Glassfish 3.1. The used projects are: `BibliotecaEAR2` (the main EAR. *'Biblioteca'* means *'Library'*), `BibliotecaEJB` (with EJBs), `BibliotecaModel` (with entities and DAOs) and `BibliotecaWeb` (The Web application). The `application.xml` has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>BibliotecaEAR2</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>BibliotecaWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>biblioteca</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>BibliotecaEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

In BibliotecaWeb, the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is written this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/google/guava-18.0.jar 
 // other JARs in BibliotecaEAR2 project
 BibliotecaEJB.jar
```

When I start the glassfish I get this warning message:

```
2014-10-20T14:34:31.691-0200|WARNING: PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/C:/dev/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/biblioteca-glass3/eclipseApps/BibliotecaEAR2/BibliotecaEJB.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\biblioteca-glass3\eclipseApps\BibliotecaEAR2\BibliotecaEJB.jar (O sistema nao pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
```

Although it does not stop me from running the application, I would like to eliminate it.

Googling for PWC6351 warning, I perceived that it happens when a used JAR is not found in the  Manifest File. However the request JAR is not simply a external library, but a sub-project in same EAR. Is there any additional configuration that should I do?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 0):

From [Packaging libraries with EARs](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/packaging_libraries_with_ears):

> When packaging applications in an EAR file, the library JARs need to
>   be placed in the archive lib directory (jars at the archive root level
>   are not added to the classpath and thus available from other EAR
>   artifacts.)
>
> The library jars placed in the "/lib" directory of the EAR (the
>   directory name can be overridden in application.xml) will be visible
>   to all sub-modules (JARs, WARs, and RARs) with no further
>   configuration. No need to add Class-Path entries in the EAR manifest.

In fact you don't need to reference the jars in the `lib` folder, and it looks like it will not work if you reference a jar on the EAR root level, like your `BibliotecaEJB.jar`.

If you don't have a real dependency from your WAR module classes to your EJB module classes you can just remove all the entries from the `MANIFEST.MF` and it should work.

If you instead have a real dependency from WAR to EJB, you may have to think about your project structure and if you really need an EAR. You can also package all the stuff into a single WAR.

The right way to use an EAR with WAR and EJB modules requires a little bit of work if your current WAR classes directly depend on classes from the EJB module:

**1. Step**

You have to create interfaces for all your "service" classes which should be available to classes in the web application (WAR).

Here is a simple example:

```
public interface FileService {

   public void showFileInformation(File file);
}
```

and

```
@Stateless
@Local(FileService.class)
@Remote(FileService.class)
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

   @Override
   public void showFileInformation(File file) {
     // here
     // is 
     // the
     // real
     // stuff
   }
}
```

**2. Step**

The next step is to package all your new interfaces into a new jar. Your model jar looks similar to this approach. If this can't be used for this purpose, create a simple java application project which gets packaged as jar and put all the interfaces into this project. This jar has to be in the `lib` folder of the EAR.

```
BibliotecaEAR2
     -- BibliotecaEJB
     -- BibliotecaWeb
     -- /lib/interfaces.jar
```

Then you have to add a dependency to this new jar in your WAR and EJB modules, so that they can find the interface classes.

**3. Step**

The services can be injected into the managed classes of your web applications (and into other service classes) like this:

```
@RequestScoped
public class FileHandler {

   // make sure to use the interface 
   @EJB
   FileService fileService;
}
```

Maybe you already have something similar to this, but then it should work without any entries in the `MANIFEST.MF`.

**See also:**

- [Maven2: Best practice for Enterprise Project (EAR file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file)
- [Java EE - EAR vs separate EJB+WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968587/java-ee-ear-vs-separate-ejbwar)
- [Packaging EJB in JavaEE 6 WAR vs EAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441237/packaging-ejb-in-javaee-6-war-vs-ear)

Comment: I have a similar issue and my project's structure is similar to what you are proposing. How do you tell Maven to include the interfaces (or the jar with the beans) in the `lib/` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved by customizing module location, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>BibliotecaEAR2</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>BibliotecaWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>biblioteca</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>BibliotecaEJB.jar</ejb>
    <bundleDir>/lib</bundleDir> <!-- ADD THIS OPTION TO THE MODULE -->
  </module>
</application>
```

This solution is taken from the [Maven EAR plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-module-location.html), which uses Maven 3 syntax, but I think you can use it too (or you can migrate to Maven 3).

Hope that helps.