# Why should I do EAR files

Tags: java, ejb, war, ear

My question is:
Why should I do EAR files ? Because I'm able to add ejb classes in simple war and it  works.
I added

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class HelloWorldBean {

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public HelloWorldBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public String hello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Hello World";

    }

}
```

and it's ok. It works. So I don't understand why should I add this class to the jar and create EAR package. Please explain me more details.

Comment: Are you able to access these EJBs using jndi names ? Or are they deployed onto your AS with given jndi name ? When you attach files in your war then you normally access them like plain java files, not EJBs.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594723/982149

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.war vs .ear file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file)

Comment: maybe I just don't understand the main reason for use EJB. 

I didn't try use JNDI but in servlet i used @EJB HelloWorldBean myBean construction so it was ok

Comment: i found more good topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968587/ear-vs-separate-ejb-war

Answer (score 0):

> In J2EE application, modules are packaged as EAR, JAR and WAR based on their functionality
>
> JAR: EJB modules which contain enterprise java beans (class files) and EJB deployment descriptor are packed as JAR files with .jar extenstion
>
> WAR: Web modules which contain Servlet class files, JSP Files, supporting files, GIF and HTML files are packaged as JAR file with .war (web archive) extension
>
> EAR: All above files (.jar and .war) are packaged as JAR file with .ear (enterprise archive) extension and deployed into Application Server.