# Is it possible to have EJBs in domain1/lib using GlassFish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I use GlassFish 4 web profile and I have the following interface and class.

```
@Local
public interface SomeService {
...
}

@Singleton
public class SomeServiceBean implements SomeService {
...
}
```

When I put interface and class in .war archive (that is in domain1/autodeplay) everything works fine. However, when I put interface and class in separate .jar archive (that is in domain1/lib) then deploying war application I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.temp.MyServlet/someService,Local 3.x interface =com.temp.SomeService,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ComponentValidator.accept(ComponentValidator.java:374) ~[dol.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.DefaultDOLVisitor.accept(DefaultDOLVisitor.java:78) ~[dol.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ComponentValidator.accept(ComponentValidator.java:123) ~[dol.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:152) ~[dol.jar:n
    ...
```

I don't use any xml descriptors. So, is it possible to have EJBs in domain1/lib and if yes, how to make EJB container find them? P.S. I tried in GF 4 full - result is the same.

Comment: If you are packaging EJBs into a separate JAR file, you should still deploy them as normal, don't treat them like a library because they aren't libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJBs cannot be added as a library to GlassFish, libraries are just added to the classpath and any annotations on them are ignored and they do not go through the EJB container. If you do want your EJBs as a seperate JAR, they can be deployed just like a WAR or EAR file.

---

In the [Glassfish reference manual](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/reference-manual.pdf) for the `add-library` command it says that it "adds the library to the class loader directory", while for the `deploy` command it says that "Applications can be...EJB modules".

Also by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/tree/master/nucleus) for Glassfish it can be worked out that all libraries are simply added to the Classloader either at launch (See [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/858c8576453101c02cc6a2f05d4b6f9ee67196c0/nucleus/admin/launcher/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/admin/launcher/GFLauncher.java#L610) and [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/858c8576453101c02cc6a2f05d4b6f9ee67196c0/nucleus/admin/launcher/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/admin/launcher/GFLauncherNativeHelper.java#L65)) or if in applibs then when the application is deployed (See [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/858c8576453101c02cc6a2f05d4b6f9ee67196c0/nucleus/deployment/common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/deployment/common/DeploymentContextImpl.java#L244)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you add any reference to GlassFish or EJB specs I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pavel_K I've added some references to glassfish manual and source